# Recyclerview GridLayout keeping top right grid empty for uneven images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using grid layout manager in recyclerview to retrieve some images. The particular code is:

```
mgridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
        mgridLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(mgridLayoutManager);

        mBlogList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

The thing is okay when I have even number of images, say 16. But when I have odd number of images, say 17, since I am using reverselayout, recyclerview starts retrieving the images (from old to new) from buttom to top. And since there are 2 columns and 17 images, it keeps the top right spot empty. It looks really silly. I guess its okay to keep the empty spot at the end of recyclerview but keeping an empty spot just at the beginning of the recyclerview seems so unimpressive. How to fix it so that there is a empty spot at the bottommost row if there are odd number of images?

Here is the Firebase database data for a particular post:
[image]

Here I am taking the link of image and using Glide to show it in the recyclerview.

The retrieving part is:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();



    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HomeBlog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<HomeBlog, BlogViewHolder>(

            HomeBlog.class,
            R.layout.profile_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase


    )
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, HomeBlog model, int position) {

            final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();

            viewHolder.setImage(post_key);

        }
    };

    mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;


    }


    public void setImage(String post_key) {


        final ImageView imagePView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profilePostImage);

        DatabaseReference val = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BlogPosts").child(post_key ) .child("image");

        val.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String ppc = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                RequestOptions placeholderRequest = new RequestOptions();
                placeholderRequest.placeholder(R.drawable.loading_background);
                try {

                    Glide.with(mView.getContext()).setDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderRequest).load(ppc).into(imagePView);

                }catch(Exception e){}

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just reverse the order of your data set and keep the LayoutManager in normal order?

Comment: How to do that? Seems like a reasonable idea.

Comment: Can you show how you construct the list of items?

Comment: U mean the database?

Comment: Sure. RecyclerView needs a list of items to show. However you create that list.

Comment: Plz che k the edited post

Comment: That doesn't explain how you retrieve and sort each entry to display in the RecyclerView.

Comment: I have added the retrieval part. About sorting, I am only using mgridLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true) to get images in sorted order

Comment: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter doesn't have a constructor like the one you seem to be using.